# Chrome history is empty

Tags: ubuntu, google-chrome

Using Chrome 121.0.6167.160 on Ubuntu 22.04. Any time I access my history it's just a blank page with "Your browsing history appears here". It's the same on all profiles. I don't know exactly when this started happening but it must have been recently, within the last couple weeks. The only setting I remember changing recently is changing the search engine from google to duckduckgo. I don't see any settings that relate to keeping history. Any idea what would cause this?

Comment: https://spreadprivacy.com/how-anonymous-is-duckduckgo/ In a nutshell, it's how DuckDuckGo is supposed to work.

Comment: I thought it might be that but it's not just DDG searches that aren't appearing in history, nothing at all is appearing, whether I access it via search or go directly to the url. Even if i switch the search engine back to google and start doing searches they don't appear.

Comment: You may check the settings in https://myactivity.google.com/product/search